# Cannot find module that doesn't exist in package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure

When taking a build from the project in Azure, the project encounters this error:

```
.\node_modules\@antv\xflow-extension\node_modules\react-color\lib\components\chrome\ChromeFields.js
Cannot find module: '@icons/material/UnfoldMoreHorizontalIcon'. Make sure this package is installed.
```

[build log picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKpbU.png)

I have used the following commands to solve the problem:

```
rm -rf ./node_module ./package-lock.json
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```

but I did not get any results. Does anyone know how I can fix the error?

Comment: Is that package even installed?

Comment: @mousetail The point is that this package does not exist in package.json

Comment: Have you tried installing it? That would add it to your package.json.

Comment: @Andy Yes, I tried it and it worked. It was surprising to me how a package that did not exist in the project caused problems

Answer (score 0):

make sure the package is in package.json:
install it with

```
npm i @icons/material
```